# Converting web-querying classes to a single generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have two classes that do that same thing with different types. I was thinking of using generics (but I am open to all options). `QueryPermissions` and the `WebQueryObjects` come from an external dll that I cannot edit.

```
 public class OnlineReportOutputService : AService, IOnlineReportOutputService
{
    public IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput> GetBy(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryOutputs = GetOutputs(id, type, reportName);
        return Mapper.Map<List<WebQueryOutput>, List<OnlineReportOutput>>(webQueryOutputs);
    }

    public StatusReturn Add(IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput> onlineReportOutputs)
    {
        return AddOrUpdate(onlineReportOutputs);
    }

    public StatusReturn Update(IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput> onlineReportOutputs)
    {
        return AddOrUpdate(onlineReportOutputs);
    }

    //Slight flaw in logic. Returning a List<StatusReturn> may be a better option but still doesn't fit rules
    //TODO: Get with original developer and see if there is a better return value
    public StatusReturn Delete(IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput> onlineReportOutputs)
    {
        var statusReturn = new StatusReturn();
        var webQueryOutputs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput>, List<WebQueryOutput>>(onlineReportOutputs);
        foreach (var webQueryOutput in webQueryOutputs)
        {
            statusReturn = _queryPermissions.DeleteWebQueryOutput(webQueryOutput);
            if (statusReturn.StatusCode.ToInt() == 500) return statusReturn;
        }
        return statusReturn;
    }

    private StatusReturn AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput> onlineReportOutputs)
    {
        var webQueryOutputs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput>, List<WebQueryOutput>>(onlineReportOutputs);
        return _queryPermissions.UpdateWebQueryOutputs(webQueryOutputs, false);
    }

    private List<WebQueryOutput> GetOutputs(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryOutputs = new List<WebQueryOutput>();
        _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryOutputs((QueryPermission.WebQueryTypes)type, ref webQueryOutputs, id, reportName);
        return webQueryOutputs;
    }
}


public class OnlineReportInputService : AService, IOnlineReportInputService
{
    public StatusReturn Add(IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput> onlineReportInputProperties)
    {
        return AddAndUpdate(onlineReportInputProperties);
    }

    public IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput> GetBy(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryInputs = GetInputs(id, type, reportName);
        return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<WebQueryInput>, List<OnlineReportInput>>(webQueryInputs);
    }

    public StatusReturn Update(IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput> onlineReportInputs)
    {
        return AddAndUpdate(onlineReportInputs);
    }

    //Slight flaw in logic. Returning a List<StatusReturn> may be a better option but still doesn't fit rules
    //TODO: Get with original developer and see if there is a better return value
    public StatusReturn Delete(IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput> onlineReportInputs)
    {
        var statusReturn = new StatusReturn();
        var webQueryInputs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput>, List<WebQueryInput>>(onlineReportInputs);
        foreach (var webQueryInput in webQueryInputs)
        {
            statusReturn = _queryPermissions.DeleteWebQueryInput(webQueryInput);
            if (statusReturn.StatusCode.ToInt() == 500) return statusReturn;
        }
        return statusReturn;
    }

    private StatusReturn AddAndUpdate(IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput> onlineReportInputProperties)
    {
        var webQueryInputs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportInput>, List<WebQueryInput>>(onlineReportInputProperties);
        return _queryPermissions.UpdateWebQueryInputs(webQueryInputs, false);
    }

    private IEnumerable<WebQueryInput> GetInputs(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryInputs = new List<WebQueryInput>();
        _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryInputs((QueryPermission.WebQueryTypes)type, ref webQueryInputs, id, reportName);
        return webQueryInputs;
    }
}
```

What I have so far:

```
 public class OnlineReportChildService<T> : IOnlineReportChildService<T>
{
    private QueryPermission _queryPermissions;

    public OnlineReportChildService()
    {
        _queryPermissions = new QueryPermission();
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> GetBy(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryOutputs = GetOutputs(id, type, reportName);
        //Not sure how to make Automapper calls generically (AMC)
        return Mapper.Map<List<WebQueryOutput>, List<OnlineReportOutput>>(webQueryOutputs);
    }

    public StatusReturn Add(IEnumerable<T> onlineReportChildren)
    {
        return AddOrUpdate(onlineReportChildren);
    }

    public StatusReturn Update(IEnumerable<T> onlineReportChildren)
    {
        return AddOrUpdate(onlineReportChildren);
    }

    //Slight flaw in logic. Returning a List<StatusReturn> may be a better option but still doesn't fit rules
    //TODO: Get with original developer and see if there is a better return value
    public StatusReturn Delete(IEnumerable<T> onlineReportChildren)
    {
        var statusReturn = new StatusReturn();
        //AMC
        var webQueryChildren = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput>, List<WebQueryOutput>>(onlineReportChildren);
        foreach (var webQueryChild in webQueryChildren)
        {
            //Different methods are called here based on type (Different)
            statusReturn = _queryPermissions.DeleteWebQueryOutput(webQueryOutput);
            if (statusReturn.StatusCode.ToInt() == 500) return statusReturn;
        }
        return statusReturn;
    }

    private StatusReturn AddOrUpdate(IEnumerable<T> onlineReportChildren)
    {
        //AMC
        var webQueryOutputs = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<OnlineReportOutput>, List<WebQueryOutput>>(onlineReportChildren);
        //Different
        return _queryPermissions.UpdateWebQueryOutputs(webQueryOutputs, false);
    }

    //These two methods could be made generic as well I imagine I just don't
    //know what to do with the calls
    protected List<WebQueryOutput> GetOutputs(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryOutputs = new List<WebQueryOutput>();
        //Different
        _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryOutputs((QueryPermission.WebQueryTypes)type, ref webQueryOutputs, id, reportName);
        return webQueryOutputs;
    }

    protected IEnumerable<WebQueryInput> GetInputs(int id, int type, string reportName)
    {
        var webQueryInputs = new List<WebQueryInput>();
        //Different         
        _queryPermissions.GetWebQueryInputs((QueryPermission.WebQueryTypes)type, ref webQueryInputs, id, reportName);
        return webQueryInputs;
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am stuck on a few spots where there are different calls for the types. I am not sure how to handle the separate calls.

I am dependency-injecting the interface into my `ApiControllers`. I would rather my `ApiControllers` only know about the service / `infrastructureObject` that they are acting upon.

With more research, what if I used [Contextual Binding with Ninject](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding)? It seems like that would give me one contract for both objects and I would still be able to keep my injections semi-clean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A First Incremental Refactoring Suggestion**

- The goal is to have working code without "major multiple organ replacement surgery" done all at once.
- Have a type parameter for each variant type.
- Keep all of your existing methods for now. Put all of them in the new class. Different signatures will keep things straight for the compiler.
- Define a `delegate` for each method that has different`_queryPermissions` calls, like `Delete` and `AddAndUpdate`. Hide the originals - make them `protected`. Make  new `public` methods, same signatures as the originals of course, and all they do is call the `delegate`
- Set the delegates in the constructor. As the refactoring evolves I wonder if you're going to need a full-blown [Abstract Factory](http://www.oodesign.com/abstract-factory-pattern.html).

> ```
> //Not sure how to make Automapper calls generically (AMC)
>     return Mapper.Map<List<WebQueryOutput>, List<OnlineReportOutput>>(webQueryOutputs);
> ```

More type parameters in the class:

```
public class OnlineReportChildService<T,U,X> : IOnlineReportChildService<T,U,X>
             where T : OnlineReportOutput
             where U : WebQueryOutput
             where X : OnlineReportOutput
```

**A Delete Delegate**

```
protected delegate StatusReturn DeleteDelegate(IEnumerable<T> In_n_Out_Burger)
```

### EDIT

Now that Dependency Injection is in the discussions:

Abstract Factory and DI seem to be two sides of the same coin. And a quick internet search finds many discussions on Factory Patterns vs Dependency Injection. Indeed, [StackOverflow has some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5698026/is-the-service-locator-pattern-any-different-from-the-abstract-factory-pattern).

In ***[Dependency Injection in .NET](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1935182501)*** the author warns "You'll need to exercise care not to use your DI Container as a [Service Locator](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/11/01/PatternRecognitionAbstractFactoryorServiceLocator/)". The author calls *Service Locator* an anti-pattern (Other do not, particularly [Martin Fowler who codified the pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)).

An extended quote:

> If you thought of DI as a SERVICE LOCATOR - that is, a general-purpose
>   Factory - this is something you need to unlearn. DI is the opposite of
>   a SERVICE LOCATOR; it's a way to structure code so that we never have
>   to imperatively ask for DEPENDENCIES. Rather, we *force* consumers to
>   supply them.

**some links**

[Service Locator is an Anti-Pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/)

[Inversion of Control Container and the Dependency Injection Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html)

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using DI to use these services. With that in mind (I realize you didn't know) I would be injecting two types into my apicontrollers that don't need to know about the other types.

Answer (score 2):

You could also keep things simple and just use OO.  Make an abstract class with two implementing subclasses.  The parts that you tagged "AMC" or "Different" would be the abstract methods.

Comment: This is an excellent idea but I don't know if I see what it saves me anything. I should have mentioned above that I am using dependency injection to access the services. Could you elaborate more on what that would give me? I apologize for not mentioning the DI.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand what difference DI might make.  You still have to inject either a parametrized instance or a non-abstract sub-class.

Comment: On what that "would give you": it just seems that what you are trying to do is not possible with generics, but it is with OO.

Comment: The second statement is what I was looking for. As I worked more with it I couldn't find a way to genericize the methods. That's a fair point and I am going to do a bit more research before I use it.

Comment: What if I used the Same Interface for the two types and used contextual binding with Ninject https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding

Comment: I must confess I am a Java programmer.  Ninject might be a good idea, but I have no experience with something similar in Java.  Java uses generics with type erasure, so this kind of thing is impossible.